# launch console application from asp.net page on shared hosting

Tags: c#, asp.net, console-application, shared-hosting

i need to launch simple console application from my asp.net webpage, that creates a file using given parameters. hereis my code:

```
string filePath = Server.MapPath(@"~/Patcher/TestPatcher.exe");

System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo info = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo(filePath , "-sn:123456789123456 -upd -fn:test.hd");
info.UseShellExecute = false; 
info.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
System.Diagnostics.Process p = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(info);

p.WaitForExit(25000);
// Display the output
string str = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
```

problem is that program doesnt create any file, but it does launch - i got some output in "str". any suggestions? and btw, that website must work on shared hosting.

Answer (score -2):

Yeah. I think you have a security issue there... you can't just run an exe from a sandboxed environment (which the browser is).

Besides the code snippet you provided, is trying to run code on the webserver, not on from the asp.net page.

Comment: sorry for that, but i just now figured out that my "patcher" application saves output file in Windows directory. any chance that i can specify "working" directory for my process?

Comment: if it accepts a directory as an argument, you'd use info.Arguments